# Assigning colour to data depending on sign of gradient (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, plot, gradient

I have two columns of data, x and y. The y data takes the shape of the triangle wave below. As you can see, the triangle has 2 sections of positive gradient and 1 longer section with a negative gradient.

[image: Triangular shape of y-data (amplitude is not important)]

I would like to write a program that:

- Queries whether the current entry in an vertical array has a positive or negative gradient with respect to the successive entry in the array.
- Then, plots the y data against x, where y values with a positive gradient (and its respective x value) are plotted using one colour, and the negative points in another colour.

How is this best done in Python?

Comment: With PIL or matplotlib. When you have specific problems, come back, we will be happy to help you.

Comment: I think I have made it as specific as possible... If you mean you would like me to offer my trial code, that's doable! I was hoping for different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filen = 'filename.txt'
x = loadtxt(fn,unpack=True,usecols=[0]) 
y = loadtxt(fn,unpack=True,usecols=[1])

n = ma.masked_where(gradient(y) < 0, y)
p = ma.masked_where(gradient(y) > 0, y)

pylab.plot(x,n,'r',x,p,'g')
```

Does the trick for me!